# Shared memory v/s physical memory

Tags: memory

I have a C++ process which is using shared memory to store and transfer data between its child processes. I want to check the shared memory usage while the parent process is executing just like top utility gives a runtime information of cpu and memory.

I am a little sceptical if the memory section in the output of top includes shared memory or not. Does it?

Comment: `top` will show not that usage information, you have to do that housekeeping yourself. One other nitpick: user processes never access physical memory, everything is virtual for them.

Comment: So when I type "df -h" I get an entry for shm as :  tmpfs                 252G     0  252G   0% /dev/shm  and when I run "free -m" I get the following output:  total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  Mem:        258202       4498     253703          0        152       2523

Comment: Basically the machine has 256 GB RAM and I was wondering, if the number shown in both mean one and the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the SHR column is supposed to show shared memory, but keep in mind that this column also includes all dynamically loaded libraries linked with your program.